# Windows Media Player showing some garbage number instead of actual Year

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-media-player

Day before I purchased new DELL Laptop which came pre-installed Windows 8 and I upgraded it to Windows 8.1 by allowing it with 800+ MB bytes update. Now its running Windows 8.1. Rebooted it. Now I copied my entire music collection from my Desktop which has Windows 7 and Windows Media Player (version 12.0.7601.18150) to new laptop. I have around 40 Gigs (10,000+ songs well tagged collection) I noticed that New windows media player on Windows 8.1 is showing some number instead of actual year for entire collection! How do i fix it? Any work around?

Comment: Found a reason for the issue. Windows Media Player for some reason is extremely slow in analyzing my music collection. When I kept WMP on.. I see message "Updating media library C:\Users\Tushar\Music" for fraction of seconds. I see correct Year value on few of my songs have started to appear! Closing the question as my problem is resolved.

Comment: Moderators... How do I close the question? My problem is solved.

Comment: If you solved your issue, considering answering your own question instead. This way people having similar issues will be able to easily find the solution (comments are not indexed).